# RenderTexture's created Image not visible

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-3.x

I'm trying to create a black and white `Sprite` based on another `Sprite`. Since I don't have access to sprite pixel data after it's been created and cached, I'm working around it by creating a new `Image` based on the , then alter the image data, then turn the `Image` into a `Texture` then finally into a `Sprite` again, now black and white.

The problem is that when I use an `Image` generated from the `RenderTexture`, it doesn't actually draw it, but when I use the png image generated by `RenderTexture::saveToFile` afterwards, it works fine.

Seems like I should be able to see `output_sprite` on the `scene` just fine, since it's being built much the same way, the only difference is the `Image` is built from an existing file on the disk versus right from the `RenderTexture`.

```cpp
cocos2d::Sprite* anvil_sprite = cocos2d::Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("anvil.png");
anvil_sprite->setAnchorPoint(Vec2::ZERO);
anvil_sprite->setPosition(0,0);

RenderTexture* rt = RenderTexture::create(anvil_sprite->getContentSize().width, anvil_sprite->getContentSize().height);
rt->begin();
anvil_sprite->visit();
rt->end();

//generates a file so I can confirm it's generating correctly in the OS's
//image viewer
rt->saveToFile("test_FILE.png");

Image* output_image = new Image;

// Either use the png generated from a previous run's RenderTexture (which works) 
// or use a new Image generated on this run.
// If I use the existing png, this works as intended, but I'd like to be 
// able to use the texture I generate right away instead of needing to save 
// it to disk first

/* OPTION A */
output_image->initWithImageFile("test_FILE.png"); // works
/* OPTION B */
output_image = rt->newImage(); //doesn't render anything

auto output_texture = new Texture2D;
output_texture->initWithImage(output_image);

Sprite* output_sprite = cocos2d::Sprite::createWithTexture(output_texture);
scene->addChild(output_sprite);
```

Beyond maybe GPU not having a chance to render out the texture before it's being used in the `Sprite`, I'm not really sure what's going to happen. I'm looking for Option A and B to both render the same way, but right now only the one with the preexisting file as a source for the `Image` is working.

Comment: I'm using v3.10, I think maybe this is a bug and it'll be resolved between now and v3.14, but I'm stuck until they add C++ support to Cocos Creator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
auto anvil_sprite = cocos2d::Sprite::create("player.png");
anvil_sprite->setAnchorPoint(Vec2::ZERO);

auto rt = RenderTexture::create(anvil_sprite->getTexture()->getPixelsWide(), anvil_sprite->getTexture()->getPixelsHigh());
rt->begin();
//Draw
anvil_sprite->visit();
rt->end();

cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getRenderer()->render();

auto img = rt->newImage(); //Generate Image
auto texture = new cocos2d::Texture2D();
texture->initWithImage(img); //Texture sprite

auto sp = cocos2d::Sprite::createWithTexture(texture); //New Sprite
sp->setPosition(cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getWinSize().width, cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getWinSize().height);
this->addChild(sp);
```

It is possible to access the pixels of the same sprite using "getData" and editing this vector using a loop or a memset as you want to work it ...

```
auto anvil_sprite = cocos2d::Sprite::create("player.png");
anvil_sprite->setAnchorPoint(Vec2::ZERO);

auto rt = RenderTexture::create(anvil_sprite->getTexture()->getPixelsWide(), anvil_sprite->getTexture()->getPixelsHigh());
rt->begin();
anvil_sprite->visit();
rt->end();

cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getRenderer()->render();

auto img = rt->newImage(); //Generate Image

auto data = img->getData();
for (size_t i = 0; i < img->getDataLen(); i++)
{
    data[i] = 400;
}
//memset(data, 400, img->getDataLen());
```

I do not know much about pixel "colors", but you can document yourself a little more in [colors](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/solved-setting-individual-pixels-in-raw-image-data-not-working/25333) if you want  ;0